# Pagination issue when limiting shown pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm working with a large list of data that I want to paginate. The pagination is working but I've been requested to limit how many pages show and add in the jump forward and back buttons. I only want to show 5 pages at a time and have the page counter adjust to only show 2 high pages and 2 lower pages. For example, if I am on page 4 I only want the pager to show 2,3,4,5,6. So here is a gif of my problem.

[See how the pager shows the page out of range for a second before it disappears?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNrDv.gif)

Here is the code that creates the pagination.

```
var pagenate = function (page, totalPages) {
        maxShownPage = page + 2;
        minShownPage = page - 2;
        pageCount = [];

        if (minShownPage <= 1 && maxShownPage <= totalPages) {
            minShownPage = 1;
            maxShownPage = 5;
        }
        if (maxShownPage > totalPages) {
            maxShownPage = totalPages;
            minShownPage = totalPages - 4;
        }

        for (i = minShownPage; i <= maxShownPage; i++) {
            pageCount.push(i);
        }

    };
```

Then inside the AngularJS method I call the pagination method like this.

```
                howManyPages = Math.ceil(visits.SurveyCount / pageSize);
                pagenate(page, howManyPages);
                $scope.pages = pageCount;
```

If you could please help me prevent the pagination from showing the page that dissapears.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using angular animate?

Comment: I am using angular animate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your issue is happening because you are using angular animate.  The `.ng-enter, .ng-enter-active, .ng-leave, .ng-leave-active` classes are causing a fading to happen so this shows the number before it gets transitioned out.  I would recommend that you create some CSS specifically for those classes to override the original functionality.

It's hard to tell you exactly what you should do without seeing your CSS, but I would just ensure that nothing is happening during those transitions.  This means that you override anything that is currently in those classes(opacity, animation-duration, etc) with the version of it that does nothing.

Comment: It turned out to be a CSS issue with the angular animate classes. I just set .ng-enter and .ng-leave to display: none; and that solved the issue.

Comment: @JustinWine that is good to hear.  So I guess my answer was correct.